# Checking a password from a text file and printing the results on a separate text file

Tags: python, file, passwords

I'm pretty new to python, very very new actually. I have an assignment where I am to check a list of passwords from a text file, run it through a function to make sure each password matches the necessary criteria and print the results on a new text file. I have the password function down but for the life of me I can't figure out how to get my results to print on the new text file. Hopefully someone can help guide me in the right direction

```
infile = open("passwdin-1.txt","r")
psswd = infile.readline()
outfile = open("passwdout.txt","w")


for pswd in infile:
    resultpsswd = checkPassw0rd(psswd) 
outfile.write(resultpsswd)

infile.close()
outfile.close()

def checkPassw0rd(psswd):

    countLength = len(psswd)
    countUC = 0
    countLC = 0
    countDigit = 0
    specialCH = 0 
    resultpsswd = psswd

    for ch in psswd:
        if ch.isupper():
            countUC += 1
        elif ch.islower():
            countLC += 1
        elif ch.isdigit():
            countDigit += 1
        elif ch in "!$%":
            specialCH = 0


    if countLength >= 6 and countUC > 0 and countLC >= 2 and countDigit > 0 and specialCH > 0:
        return True, resultpsswd "Password is valid and accepted"
    else:
        resultpsswd == "Password is invalid and not accepted"
        if countLength < 6:
            resultpsswd == resultpsswd + "\n Password has to be at least 6 characters long. "
        if countUC == 0:
            resultpsswd == resultpsswd + "\n Password has to have at least one upper case character. "
        if countLC == 0:
            resultpsswd == resultpsswd + "\n Password has to have at least one lower case character. "
        if countDigit == 0:
            resultpsswd == resultpsswd + "\n Password has to have at least one digit. "
        if specialCH == 0:
            resultpsswd == resultpsswd + "n\ Password has to have at least one of the special charaters '!$%'. "

        return False, resultpsswd
```

Comment: I think the argument to pass to `checkPassw0rd` should be `pswd` and not `psswd`. Also the `outfile.write` statement should be indented, so that you execute it for each password. What is exactly the problem you see?

Comment: Also you should close the files once you're done reading/writing.

Comment: I get an error saying the write argument should be a str not a tuple

Comment: That's because your `checkPassw0rd` function returns `False, resultpsswd`. Change this to only return `resultpsswd`.

Comment: Of course if you need the "True/False" information too you should modify your code so that only the `resultpsswd` part is written to file, but at the moment you're not using the `True/False` information.

Comment: That’s actually what i need to do, i need the resultpsswd from the checkpassw0rd function write in file

Answer (score 0):

there is a typo in your code with the argument you pass to the check pwd function and there is an indentation issue, even if it did work you would only write the last password to file

changing your code to something like the below should fix it

```
with open("passwdout.txt","w") as outfile:
    [outfile.write(checkpasw0rd(pswd)) for pswd in infile]
```

the `with statement` ensures you do not need to close the outfile anymore, this is handled automatically

use the code above to replace your entire forloop

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to sum up what you could make it to have your example work.

1. First of all you should close the files you use once you've used them
2. In the piece of code 
   `for pswd in infile:
       resultpsswd = checkPassw0rd(psswd)`
   you should pass `pswd` to your `checkPassw0rd` function
3. The output of your `checkPassw0rd` function is a tuple (,  resultpsswd), so you should only consider the second item of that tuple:

   `okNok, resultpsswd = checkPassw0rd(psswd)
    outfile.write(resultpsswd)`
4. You should indent the line `outfile.write(resultpsswd)`.

In the end something like that should work:

```
infile = open("passwdin-1.txt","r")
psswd = infile.readline()
infile.close()

#outfile = open("passwdout.txt","w") --> Better to use the with statement

with open("passwdout.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for pswd in infile:
        okNok, resultpsswd = checkPassw0rd(pswd) 
        outfile.write(resultpsswd)

#No need to explicitly close the file, the with statement will do it
```

I hope this helps.